# What happend when import deprecated lib in react native?

Tags: react-native

Today I review the code in our project. I found some component import from react-native is deprecated. Like Clipboard in react-native version 0.61.5
Is it can make the app is crash?
[image]

Of course, we'll replace with @react-native-community/clipboard but I'm confusing

Comment: it's obvious what happens, your app might not properly work for new android versions for ex android 10

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a new project. People update react-native but still use deprecated libs I'm replacing them. I guest it can make app crash

Comment: So you need to exclude your new implementation for new users and let old-users to use deprecated lib if it works perfect for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of React native Component have been change and support by @react-native-community ,

Just follow the doc, install the lib :

npm install --save @react-native-community/clipboard

And import it in your component :

import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard';

delete the import from react-native,

If you are lucky all will work and will be support with last OS,

Answer (score 0):

With react-native version 0.61.5 just warning but the app still not crash